# Child State not updating after setState on parent page

Tags: reactjs

I have a React page that I use in 2 routes: /test/new and test/edit/:id. The problem I have is that when I am in /test/edit/:id and I do a history.push("/test/new") I get the value of the input cached and I don't know how to clean it.

**Routes:**

I am using the same page for both routes so I don't have to duplicate the code and I would like to keep it like this.

```
<Route exact path={`/test/edit/:id`} component={TestSection}></Route>
<Route exact path={`/test/new`} component={TestSection}></Route>
```

**Parent Component:**

I have extracted from the parent component only the lines for which I need help, actually my page has more things but in order not to have to read all the code I have simplified the section as much as I could.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useHistory, useParams } from "react-router";
import { UseGet, UseWeb } from "../../hooks/http";
import TestInput from "./TestInput";
import Preloader from "../../components/preloader/Preloader";

const TestSection = (props) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const history = useHistory();
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState();
  const [category, setCategory] = useState();
  const [IsLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);


  const fetchCategory = async (id) => {
    const response = await UseGet(UseWeb("/categories/get"),
      { data: { term: "_id", value: id } }
    );
    setCategory(response.outputData[0])
    setIsLoading(false)
  };



  const handleNew = () => {
    setCategory(undefined)
    history.push('/test/new')
  };



  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      fetchCategory(id).then((category) => {
        setCategory(category);
      });
    } else {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);


  return (

    <div className="container" style={{ maxWidth: "600px", padding: "90px" }}>
      <Preloader loading={IsLoading} />
      {!IsLoading && <React.Fragment>
        <TestInput
          label="Title"
          name="title"
          value={category?.title}
          error={errors?.title}
        />
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleNew}>Add new</button>
      </React.Fragment>
      }
    </div>

  );
};

export default TestSection;
```

**Child Component**

In the child component I did the same as in the parent component, I extracted only the relevant code so I didn't have to interpret everything. Actually the child component does more things.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { FormGroup, Label } from "reactstrap";


const TestInput = (props) => {
  const { value, name, error, copy, size, className, label, counter, onChange, ...rest } = props;
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(value);


  const handleChange = (ev) => {
    setInputValue(typeof onChange === "function" ? onChange(ev) : ev.target.value)
  };

  console.log(value)

  useEffect(() => {

  }, [])

  return (
    <FormGroup className="mb-2">

      {label && <Label className="form-label fs-13px" htmlFor={name}>
        {label}
        {error && <span className="field-error">{error}</span>}
      </Label>}

      <div className={`form-control-wrap`}>
        <input
          type="text" id={name} value={inputValue} name={name}
          className={`form-control form-control-${size ? size : "sm"} ${className}`}
          onChange={handleChange}
          {...rest}
        />
      </div>
    </FormGroup>
  );
};

export default TestInput;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say it is a good idea to have 2 routes with exactly the same component. If they are the same component, why not just use the same page?

One solution could be to create separate components for each route and then wrap the reusable component in these route components. For example:

```
<Route exact path={`/test/edit/:id`} component={Page1}></Route>
<Route exact path={`/test/new`} component={Page2}></Route>
```

And then:

```
const Page1 = () => {
  return <TestSection />
}

const Page2 = () => {
  return <TestSection />
}
```

This will create separate instances for each `TestSection` and state should reset on mount each time.

Comment: I often take code reuse to these extremes, but it is absolutely true, if they are two different paths it makes no sense to point to the same component. Thank you very much for your help.